# Change IR "Primary Report" label

Tags: oracle-apex

Apex 4.1.1.00.23

Can I change the IR default Reports label from "1. Primary Report"?

I found this code, and it works for the page load, but changes back to the default when the page changes or other saved reports are picked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        changeIRText('1. Default');
    }); // end of ready function
  function changeIRText(pText){
        $('select#apexir_SAVED_REPORTS').find('option').each(function(index,elem) {
            $(elem).text(function(i, text) {
                        return text.replace('1. Primary Report', pText);
                }); // end of changing text
            });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the report is paginated, the html source is also replaced. You need to bind to the `apexafterrefresh` event on the IR region aswell, or create a dynamic action which fires on the "After Refresh" framework event, with triggering element the IR region. 
You can best achieve a manual bind through assigning a static id to the IR

```
$("#my_ir_report").bind("apexafterrefresh", function(){changeIRText('1. Default');});
```

### Code in page attributes

Rightclick the page and select edit.
Go to the "Javascript" region.
[image: javascript in page attributes]

### In a dynamic action

Put the javascript function in the page attributes. This is good for code reusability. However, if you don't use it outside the dynamic action, consider simply putting the code in the dynamic action. There is less harm though, as when you will see the dynamic action and inspect the code it runs you'll see that it calls a function, and you'll know that that will be in the page attributes or an external javascript file.

Create a dynamic action, type Advanded. Fire on after refresh, and select your IR region.

Dynamic action properties:
[image: Dynamic action properties]

In the true action, select Execute javascript as action. Put in your code. When the dynamic action has been created by the wizard, go back into the true action properties and make sure you check the 'Fire on Page Load' checkbox! This will make sure that not only your code will run when the report is refreshed, but also when page loading is complete, and saves creating another dynamic action!

True action properties:
[image: True action properties]

***In closing***
Being unfamiliar with javascript is fine, you'll pick it up over time. But do pick up some dynamic action knowledge! Don't cram script tags over your page, they'll be much harder to maintain and harder to remember if and where they are!
[Oracle tutorial on dynamic actions](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/apex/r40/apexdynactions/apexdynactions_ll.htm#t6)
[Skillbuilders youtube tutorial on dynamic actions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe3JvYUxMnY)

Comment: The code in my question goes where?  Your one line of code goes where?    Thanks!

Comment: @RMANExpress I edited my answer to give 2 examples of where to put the code!

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for the delay in getting back to this question, had another fire to put out.

Comment: "You need to bind to the apexafterrefresh event on the IR region aswell, or create a dynamic action"    

Or?  Using just the "Code in page attributes" solution, the "1. Default" report label changes back to "Primary" when another saved report is picked.  I added the dynamic action, and it is now working.  Now that I added the Dynamic Action code, do I still need the code in the "Execute when page loads" in the Page Attributes?  I removed it and it is working.

Comment: @RMANExpress i saw i made a small error with the page attributes code: the `apexafterrefresh` code has a small change to it: wrap the `changeirtext` function in an anonymous function, then it works! And indeed: or. Use the manual bind to the event, or use the dynamic action - whichever you prefer, although i recommend dynamic actions. If you go with the dynamic action, you don't need the code in the "execute when page loads" indeed, as this will be handled in the dynamic action!